# Stylesheets 403 Forbidden Local Host Codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

I am almost done with my theme system for my codeigniter.

Come across a issue with style sheets have error 403 local host.

It was working on my other one but my new version will not pick up

Each theme has its on style sheet folder and java script. Most people say its wrong to do it that way but. This way is much more better for theme system.

**theme/default**

**theme/default/stylesheets/stylesheet.css**

**theme/default/javascript/common.js**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<title><?php echo $this->config->item('title'); ?></title>
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application/views/theme/default/stylesheets/stylesheet.css" media="screen">    
</head>
```

**theme/codeigniter**

**theme/codeigniter/stylesheets/stylesheet.css**

**theme/codeigniter/javascript/common.js**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<title><?php echo $this->config->item('title'); ?></title>
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application/views/theme/codeigniter/stylesheets/stylesheet.css" media="screen" >
</head>
```

Comment: As I said i know that about should be stored in web root like link says but need themes have its on style sheets like shown above. I know all about the other way just trying to make it my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think direct access inside the applications folder will be revoked by the Code Ignitor. Hence, i put all put all images,CSS and JS in a folder named assets in the CI ROOT FOLDER, along with applications, system & user_guide.

Now, Make a file named `utility_helper.php` in `ROOT_FOLDER/application/helper` and add the following code

```
<?php

function asset_url(){
   return base_url().'assets/';
}

?>
```

then add utility to `application/config/autoload.php` at line 67

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('utility');
```

Now when ever you want to access the asset folder, you can call it as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo asset_url();?>stylesheets/stylesheet.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href=<?php echo   
  base_url()."application/views/theme/codeigniter/stylesheets/stylesheet.css"?> />
```

Comment: So what is this? How to use it? How relates it to the question?